# SSH ecdsa-sha2 key changed?

Tags: ssh, yubikey

I use a yubikey with device-generated ssh keys to login on my servers.
A few months ago I've created a ssh keypair on our cloud provider (OVH) with this value (truncated):

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAA...oYuQ= cardno:123
ssh-ed25519 AAAA...dOjE cardno:123
```

I've then launched an instance and I was able to connect to it.
Then a few weeks ago I wasn't able to connect to SSH anymore, I was getting access denied.

I've today decided to look into it and rebooted the instance in recovery mode and found that the ssh authorized key value was:

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAA...dOjE= cardno:123
```

however running `ssh-add -L` my yubikey is showing

```
ssh-ed25519 AAAA...dOjE cardno:123
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAA...iDk= cardno:123
```

so the `ssh-ed25519` key matches the cloud provider keypair but the `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256` doesn't.

I can confirm that there's no way (on openstack) to edit a key and the key details show it was created a few months ago (so it has always been the same since the instance has been created).

The certificates shown on `gpg --card-status` have been created in 2022 so before the keypair was set on the cloud provider, so those didn't change.

A while ago I've reset the card PIV because I've used the wrong PIN too many times and re-linked it to my mac os login, could that reset have replaced the `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256` key? If that's the case why the `ssh-ed25519` key is the same?